# A basis of a diagonalized symmetric bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, diagonalization

The symmetric bilinear form $b$ on $\mathbb{Q}^{3}$ is represented by the matrix with respect to the standard basis
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 3 & -2 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & -2 & 1\end{array}\right) \in \operatorname {Mat}_{3,3}(\mathbb{Q})$$

(a) Determine a basis of $ \mathbb{Q}^{3}$ with respect to which $b$ is represented by a diagonal matrix.

(b) Now consider $A$ as an element of $ \operatorname{Mat}_{3,3}(\mathbb {R})$and determine a $S \in \mathrm{ GL}_{3}(\mathbb {R})$ such that $S^{t} A S$  is a diagonal matrix with entries in  $\{-1,0,1\}$

My approach:

(a) Since $b$ is symmetric it follows that $b(v,w) = v^T\cdot A \cdot w = w^T\cdot A \cdot v = b(w,v)$.

Now the eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix are always orthogonal. We have the eigenvalues as $\lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2 = 2, \lambda_3 = 5$ with the corresponding eigenvectors:

$ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -0.5 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

and $b(v_1,v_2) = b(v_1,v_3) = b(v_2,v_3) = 0$. However I'm not satisfied with my answer because I'm not sure about the diagonal matrix for $b$.

I thought it might be the jordan form ? $$J=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5\end{array}\right) \in \operatorname {Mat}_{3,3}(\mathbb{Q})$$

but  $b(\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}) ≠ 0$.

So is $v_1,v_2,v_3$ still the basis I'm looking for? I have probably some deeper misconception about this. Let me know where I got wrong.

(b) What is a good approach to start with (b). Is it possible to use (a)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It seems to me like you are mixing up your understanding of Linear Maps with that of Bilinear maps. The representation of a bilinear map in a basis $(e_i)$ is that the $i$-th row, $j-th$ column is $b(e_i,e_j)$ right? When you write $b((-1,0,0),(0,2,0))$, how do you go about computing it (why these vectors, in what bases?)? I think investigating this should clear things up for you.

Comment: @Pastudent I just put the first 2 columns of $J$ in my bilinear map and get $$b(\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}) = (-1 , 0 , 0) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 3 & -2 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & -2 & 1\end{array}\right) \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}= (4)$$

Comment: Remember that $J$ is the representation of $b$ in another basis and $A$ is the representation of $A$ in the canonical basis. You are mixing up the two, so this computation is not very meaningful.

Comment: Call $Q$ the change of basis matrix from $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ to $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$. Then the representation matrix of $b$ in the basis of eigenvectors $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is the matrix $B = Q^TAQ$. It might be a good exercise to compute this, as this should clear the relationships up.

Comment: @Pastudent So $B = Q^TAQ$ contains the basis of the eigenvectors as the columns? But isn't the change of basis matrix from $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ to $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ just the matrix $Q = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and we have $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1/2 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1/2 & 1 \\ 2 & -2 & 1 \end{array}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 3 & -2 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & -2 & 1\end{array}\right) \cdot \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1/2 & -1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1/2 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} -9/4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 9/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 45 \end{array}\right)$$ and the columns is my basis?

Comment: Your computation looks correct (haven't verified) and you have now found the diagonal matrix for $b$, let's call it $D$. You now have two ways of computing $b(u,w)$: 1) Take $u = u_1e_1 + \cdots + u_3 e_3$ (and $w$) in the canonical basis and compute $b(u,w)$ by doing $(u_1,u_2,u_3) A (w_1,w_2,w_3)^T$. 2) You write $u$ as a linear combination of the Eigenvectors $u'_1v_1 + u'_2v_2 + u'_3v_3$ (same for $w$) and you now have $b(u,w) = (u'_1,u'_2,u'_3) D (w'_1,w'_2,w'_3)^T$. Both operations should give you the same result. This example illustrates how changes of basis work in the bilinear case.

Comment: @Pastudent, thank you for the clarification. Regarding solving (b), I was considering utilizing Sylvester's law of inertia. It states that the presence of $-1$ and $1$ on the diagonal depends solely on the bilinear form $b$ and is independent of the chosen basis. But how can I see that from my bilinear form?Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: The usual way of solving this type of exercise is to modify your basis accordingly. Start with $D$. You want to muliply the first column by $4/9$. If you multiply $D$ to the left and to the right by a matrix with diagonal $(\sqrt{4/9}, \sqrt{2/9}, \sqrt{45})$, you can modify $Q$ accordingly. The Idea is that when modifying $D$, every operation has to be separated in two operations. One to the left, one to the right, as you multiply by $Q^T$ from the left and $Q$ from the right.